# Extract URL link from src attribute of script tag in html through XSLT

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

Is there a way to extract URL link specified inside src attribute of  tag in a HTML file using XSLT?

The HTML file is like this -

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<SCRIPT language="javascript" src="http://myspace.com" type="text/javascript"></script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

How do I code this in XSLT? I want to extract the URL in a variable which I then use it to pass to another function.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `xsl:variable` to store an attribute value. Later, refer to it as `$name-of-variable`.

I have slightly adapted your input HTML, that is, lowercased all element names. It is uncommon to have uppercase names in HTML. Besides, your `script` element ends with a lowercased name anyway, which renders it malformed because XML names are case-sensitive.

Do not overcomplicate things. Depending on what you actually want to achieve it might not be necessary to store the attribute value in a variable.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:variable name="link" select="//script/@src"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <link>
         <xsl:value-of select="$link"/>
      </link>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<link>http://myspace.com</link>
```